# Add one minute to a date field in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

When my template is rendered, I create a schedule into a null collection. The data looks as follows:

```
{
  _id: "someid",
  day: "Saturday",
  start: Date,
  end: Date,
  jobs: [{
    _id: '123',
    start: Date,
    end: Date
  }, {
    _id: '567',
    start: Date,
    end: Date
  }]
}
```

Every minute, I want to update every entry to be the date plus one minute. I can do the following

```
Template.schedule.onCreated(function () {
  Meteor.setInterval(function () {
    DaySchedule.update({}, {
      $inc: {
        'start': ???,
        'end': ???,
        'cycles.start': ???,
        'cycles.end': ???
      },
    });
  });
});
```

How can this be done with mongodb?

Comment: You could save the date as actual timestamp instead of Date object and use $inc to increment. However it's NOT a good idea to perform a single op against a database every minute and for a kinda of *known value*. I mean theres's not sense to store such value

Answer (score 3):

`$inc` for dates and times is not implemented yet: [SERVER-3174](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3174).

So your best bet is to calculate new values in your app and then do the `$set`.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the date as an integer representation instead of Date object and use $inc to increment. When *consuming* you would retrieve the number and turn into a Date.

You could always use `$set` as Sergio's answers suggests.

**However it's NOT a good idea to perform a single op against a database every minute and for a kinda of *known value*. I mean theres's not sense to store such value in these sort of logics.**

Comment: When you say "actual timestamp", do you mean "unix timestamp"? It's not "actual", it's integer representation. Actual value would be a `DateTime` object (as the OP has already).

Comment: You're right, I mean the integer representation. Do you agree there's not sense to use MongoDB or a DATABASE for this?

Comment: Why not? I'm sure there are valid reasons to do this kind of stuff. It's not clear if it's the case here, though (too little info in the question)

Comment: From my opinion, as I see this `setInterval` function, looks like date is being stored there to be ever incremented